# Android publishing flavour based artifact on Artifactory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I am trying publish flavour based artifact on my Artifactory server. Gradle code looks like this

```
def GroupId = 'com.example.directory'
def ArtifactId = 'demo
def Version = '0.0.1-IB1''


productFlavors {
    extended {
        ArtifactId = "extended"
    }
    mini {
        ArtifactId = "mini"
    }    
}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

                groupId GroupId
                version Version
                artifactId ArtifactId
               
                def filename = "${archivesBaseName}-${variant.baseName}.aar"
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${filename}")
            }
                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    def deps = configurations.implementation.allDependencies + configurations.api.allDependencies
                    deps.each {
                        if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified" == it.name) && it.version != null && "unspecified" != it.version) {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://artifactoryUrl/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = GroupId
            username = "${userName}"
            password = "${pass}"

        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run gradle command it generates the specific flavour + build type artifact. But while publishing it tries to publish all varient of the library and throws an error for other aar file names.

```
./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :demo:assembleextendedrelease && ./gradlew :demo:artifactoryPublish
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, It looks like you have a compilation error in line 2 - missing ' after the 'demo

Comment: could you please also provide the error you encountered?